How to translate names or description in Geometry Node
I want to add more language translations to the parameters of the geometric node group.

However, after searching on Google, I did not find any information related to language translation, which is very rare.
I tried using the 'bpy.app.translations.register()' function in Python, but it didn't work.
I think Blender's own language translation can translate some vocabulary.

What exactly did I do wrong?

Hello, my understanding is that Blender comes with a builtin dictionary of translatable words or expressions, but you can also provide your own for the purpose of translating the interface in an extension. I don't know if it's possible to override translation in geometry node socket tooltips, though

Found The Blender Developer Handbook page on translations, it might be of use to you. Hope it helps!
